# How can I count the occurrences of a string within a file?

Tags: bash, search

Just take this code as an example. Pretending it is an HTML/text file, if I would like to know the total number of times that `echo` appears, how can I do it using bash?

```
new_user()
{
    echo "Preparing to add a new user..."
    sleep 2
    adduser     # run the adduser program
}

echo "1. Add user"
echo "2. Exit"

echo "Enter your choice: "
read choice


case $choice in
    1) new_user     # call the new_user() function
       ;;
    *) exit
       ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This will output the number of *lines* that contain your search string.

```
grep -c "echo" FILE
```

This won't, however, count the number of occurrences in the file (ie, if you have echo multiple times on one line).

edit:

After playing around a bit, you could get the number of occurrences using this dirty little bit of code:

```
sed 's/echo/echo\n/g' FILE | grep -c "echo"
```

This basically adds a newline following every instance of echo so they're each on their own line, allowing grep to count those lines. You can refine the regex if you only want the word "echo", as opposed to "echoing", for example.

Comment: So what can i do if there are few echo in the same line?
eg. echo time echo a echo

Comment: I've updated my response which should hopefully work for you.

Comment: Thanks . Spend you a few more minute ,One more question . if i would like to delete the third occurance of echo . what can i do?

Comment: @foodil: Remove 3rd echo : `sed -e 's/echo//3'`

Comment: Can i assign the number of occurance in a variable like this?:
noOfTable1=grep -c "table_1row" /var/www/html/INFOSEC/english/news/test.html

thanks

Comment: @foodil: noOfTable1=`$(grep ...)`

Answer (score 207):

The number of string occurrences (not *lines*) can be obtained using `grep` with `-o` option and `wc` (word count):

```
$ echo "echo 1234 echo" | grep -o echo
echo
echo
$ echo "echo 1234 echo" | grep -o echo | wc -l
2
```

So the full solution for your problem would look like this:

```
$ grep -o "echo" FILE | wc -l
```

Comment: I feel it's simple solution, not sure about time complexity

Comment: Be careful if grep thinks the file is "binary" you'll get a "1" output from this every time, add `-a` just to be safe if you like...

Comment: I think this is a better answer than the accepted answer.

Comment: This is giving incorrect result (lesser number) for a 6GB XML file with only one line. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58994637/5524175 worked for me. This is my command: `grep -o '<wd:Report_Entry>' file.xml | wc -l`. I'm on macOS.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76968047/grep-command-for-counting-no-of-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-file-giving-lesser

Answer (score 3):

None of the existing answers worked for me with a single-line 10GB file. Grep runs out of memory even on a machine with 768 GB of RAM!

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal
MemTotal:       791236260 kB
$ ls -lh test.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 me all 9.2G Nov 18 15:54 test.json
$ grep -o '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,' test.json  | wc -l
grep: memory exhausted
0
```

So I wrote [a very simple Rust program to do it](https://crates.io/crates/count_occurences).

1. [Install Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install).
2. `cargo install count_occurences`

```
$ count_occurences '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,' test.json
99094198
```

It's a little slow (1 minute for 10GB), but at least it doesn't run out of memory!

Comment: How do I see the source code of count_occurences?

Comment: Nvm. I figured this out - https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-see-the-code-for-crate-published-in-crate-io/1897/2

Comment: https://github.com/Timmmm/count_occurences/blob/master/src/main.rs

Comment: @Timmmm : if you're having `10GB` single line files, time to revisit and restructure the data

Comment: The fact that it was on a single line is irrelevant (JSON decoders don't care). 10GB of JSON is more or less unworkable no matter how many new lines it has in it! We switched to SQLite in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking some guesses here, because I don't quite understand what you're asking.

I think that what you want is a count of the number of lines on which the pattern 'echo' appears in the given file.

I've pasted your sample text into a file called `6741967`.

First, `grep` finds the matches:

```
james@Brindle:tmp$grep echo 6741967 
    echo "Preparing to add a new user..."
echo "1. Add user"
echo "2. Exit"
echo "Enter your choice: "
```

Second, use `wc -l` to count the lines

```
james@Brindle:tmp$grep echo 6741967  | wc -l
       4
```

Comment: thanks your help . Sorry for making you confusing. My question is to count the number of occurrences in the file

Comment: If you do grep -o echo 6741967 it will output a new line for each of them, then you can use: grep -o echo 6741967 | wc -l and it will account for multiple 'echo's on a single line as well

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
awk -v RS='echo' 'END{print NR - (NR ? 1 : 0)}' file
```

With the above we're counting the number of `whatever...echo` "records" in the input. The `- (NR ? 1 : 0)` is so we don't count the string after the last `echo` in the input (input `foo...echo...bar` should report `1`, not `2`) and so we print `0` instead of `-1` for an empty input file.

Since the above is reading each `echo`-separated string one at a time it will handle very large files containing multiple `echo`s better than `grep -o echo` which apparently tries to read the whole input into memory at once and then split it up.

Answer (score -2):

if you just want the number of occurences then you can do this,
$ grep -c "string_to_count" file_name

Comment: Won't count the string happening twice on the same line correctly.