# How to loop through all files in a directory and find if a value exists in those files using a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a directory `PAYMENT`. Inside it I have some text files.

```
xyx.txt
agfh.txt
hjul.txt
```

I need to go through all these files and find how many entries in each file contain text like `BPR`.

If it's one I need to get an alert. For example, if `xyx.txt` contains only one `BPR` entry, I need to get an alert.

Comment: possible duplicate of [count all occurrences of string in lots of files with grep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371115/count-all-occurrences-of-string-in-lots-of-files-with-grep)

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to loop, something like this should make it:

```
grep -l "BPR" /your/path/PAYMENT/*
```

- `grep` is a tool to find lines matching a pattern in files.
- `-l` shows which files have that string.
- `"BPR"` is the string you are looking for.
- `/your/path/PAYMENT/*` means that it will `grep` throughout all files in that dir.

In case you want to want to find within specific kind of files / inside directories, say so because the command would vary a little.

---

### Update

Based on your new requests:

> I need to go through all these files an find how many entries in each
>   file like BPR.
>
> If its one I need to get an alert. For example, if xyx.txt contains
>   only one BPR entry, I need to get an alert.

`grep -c` is your friend ([more or less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741967/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-file-using-bash)). So what you can do is:

```
if [ "$(grep -c a_certain_file)" -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "mai dei mai dei"
fi
```

Comment: Did you change `/your/path` to your real path? If you are in `PAYMENT`, you can simply do `grep -l "BPR" *`, for example.

Comment: Sorry brother, now its working. i have change it. but i did a small mistake :(. im in rush, i have to complete it within 1 hour.

Comment: But ths is not the solution that i need. sorry about my bad explanation in my question

Comment: `grep -c` will count the ocurrences. For the `i need to get an alert`, please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

`i need to go through all these files an find is there an entry like 'BPR'`

If you are looking for a command to find file names that contain `BPR` then use:

```
echo /path/to/PAYMENT/*BPR*.txt
```

If you are looking for a command to find file names that contain text `BPR` then use:

```
grep -l "BPR" /path/to/PAYMENT/*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

`grep -o BPR {path}/* | wc -l`

where {path} is the location of all the files. It'll give you JUST the number of occurrences of the string "BPR".

Also, FYI - this has also been talked about here: [count all occurrences of string in lots of files with grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371115/count-all-occurrences-of-string-in-lots-of-files-with-grep)