# List all files which contain specific word

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, command, command-prompt

In my project, I've called one method in multiple files. I want to see all files in which that method is called. Using command line, is there a way to list all files which contain specific word?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to loop through all files in a directory and find if a value exists in those files using a shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226930/how-to-loop-through-all-files-in-a-directory-and-find-if-a-value-exists-in-those)

Answer (score 0):

You could use grep

```
grep [word_to_find] [files]
```

For example, find all method definitions in python files

```
grep def *.py
```