# How to find no. of times a character has occured in bash string?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I have a string in bash $str.

```
str="ayushmishraalightayushas"
```

I want to find no of times the letter **'a'** occured in the string.

Comment: And also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6741967/1983854, although the accepted answer is not to be followed.

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished using `grep -o` plus `wc`:

```
$ echo "ayushmishraalightayushas" | grep -o 'a' | wc -l
5
```

As the first `grep -o` shows:

```
$ echo "ayushmishraalightayushas" | grep -o 'a'
a
a
a
a
a
```

because the `-o` option of grep does:

> -o, --only-matching
>
> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each
>   such part on a separate output line.

and then it is just a matter of counting the number of lines with the `wc -l` command.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
echo ayushmishraalightayushas | grep -o a | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

This awk one-liner is simplest I believe to get this count without needing multiple piped commands:

```
str='ayushmishraalightayushas'
awk -F a '{print NF-1}' <<< "$str"
5
```