# Count number of occurrences in a file

Tags: unix, awk

I have the following rows in my data

```
029 32389047809475037568907376 000000 00000000000
029 32389047809475037568907376 000000 00000000000
029 32389047809475037568907376 000000 00000000000
029 32389047809475037568907376 000000 00000000000
029 32389047809475037568907376 000000 00000000000
```

and I want to count number of "029"s beginning in these rows in my log view.

How do I do that?

Comment: This is a bit broad. Could you be a bit more specific and show some input data, expected output and what you have tried so far?

Comment: @fedorqui A bit broad is an understatement!

Comment: Right now i can't post a picture to let you know the file.But, i can tell the file and its pattern:

Comment: 029 32389047809475037568907376 000000 00000000000 this kind of rows are millions and i want to count number of 029 in these rows.Please help me

Comment: No, please `edit` your question to show this, since code or text does not show properly in comments. You may want to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: So you want to know how many times `029` appears in general? or in the beginning of a line? or how many lines have `029`? Please clarify it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I count the occurrences of a string within a file using bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741967/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-file-using-bash)

Answer (score 2):

A solution without awk:

```
grep -c "^029" file
```

find all lines starting with 029 and count them (thats what the `-c` option does)

Comment: How do i convert this huge log file into "file"(text format/any format) as you mentioned ?

Comment: Use `grep -c` instead

Comment: @martin these rows are a million in my log file i.e after i write command  " view cid_generation.GG.20150422.rpt " so i can perform only a limited operations when i view this file.

Comment: @martin so where will the contents of my file go? as metioned _view ... | grep -c "^029" file_ will they go into the file?

Comment: No, just do `view .. | grep -c "^029"`, without the file, @subash

Answer (score 1):

You could use `uniq` for this:

```
$ uniq -cw 3 file
      5 029 32389047809475037568907376 000000 00000000000
```

Options:

> -c, --count
>                 prefix lines by the number of occurrences
>
> -w, --check-chars=N
>                 compare no more than N characters in lines

---

If you don't have the `-w` option for your version of `uniq` a standard `awk` solution would be:

```
$ awk '/^029 /{c++}END{print c}' file
5
```

Comment: That is a nice solution with `uniq`, I didn't now that.

Comment: You will need a version of GNU uniq for the -w option. OSX is a BSD variant so you will have to install the GNU coreutils with your favourite package manager for all the extra goodies.