# Code about occurences of a word in a file in BASH

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I want to count the occurences of a word in a file with only *one* line of code. Example: for the input: "hi, welcome to the himalaya. hihi" "hi" the output will be 4 (because the word "hi" occurs 4 times)

I tried using tr and grep, but it doesn't count "hihi" twice, but only once.

```
tr 'WORD' '\n' < $1 | grep $2 | wc -l
```

For the given example above, the output was 3 instead of 4. 
Thank you!

Comment: `grep -o "$2" "$1" | wc -l`? (if `$1` is a filename...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I count the occurrences of a string within a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741967/how-can-i-count-the-occurrences-of-a-string-within-a-file). The exact answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14510665/3832970).

Comment: `perl -nE 'BEGIN { $/ = shift } END { say $. - ($. && 1) }' "$2" "$1"`?

Comment: @GunTop if `hihi` is 2 `hi`s then you aren't counting **words**, you're counting **strings**. Words are strings of word-consituent characters (typically alpha-numeric plus underscore) separated by non-word-constituent characters (punctuation, spaces, etc.). When counting **words** `hi` only appears once in the input `"hi, welcome to the himalaya. hihi"`.

Comment: Thank you all, guys! you're awesome. I'll try these codes out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you tagged the question with `awk`:

```
awk '{s+=gsub(/WORD/,1)}END{print s}' file
```

thus, a single process solution, also possible to be extended.

Comment: Thank you.
What does 'gsub' , 'END', and 's' mean?

Comment: @GunTop read some awk tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
grep -o "hi" input.txt | wc -l
```